# how to access ejabberd`s mnesia directly?

Tags: ejabberd

ejabberd is running on ubuntu,version is 2.1.13,only one node,not distributed,and i want to query it`s mnesia database in **ejabberdctl debug** shell

i have tried use **tv:start()** in **ejabberdctl debug** shell,but it return

```
undefined function tv:start/0
```

i also tried

```
Cookie = 'MY_COOKIE'.
EjabberdNode = 'ejabberd@localhost'.
erlang:set_cookie(EjabberdNode, Cookie).
** exception error: distribution_not_started
   in function  auth:set_cookie/2 (auth.erl, line 119)
net_adm:ping(EjabberdNode).
rpc:call(EjabberdNode, mnesia, system_info, [tables]).
```

as you can see, i got an error seems for distribution.

and how to query tables in mnesia with a shell like mysql shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here my first node is **ejabberd@localhost**,for access mnesia of first node,we build another node **test@localhost** whitch generate a cluster with first node,and then you can access mnesia.

command:

```
 erl -sname test -mnesia dir '"/tmp/"' -mnesia extra_db_nodes "['ejabberd@ubuntu']" -s mnesia
```

attention: -sname test,must not same as the first node name,here is **ejabberd**
then start mnesia by command

```
mnesia:start().
```

then you can check mnesia by command

```
 mnesia:info().
```

good luck~